# Gitlab CI/CD pipleline fails to login to docker although the certificate is available

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to push an image to a custom docker registry running on a private machine. Assuming the registry is available at `reg.xxxx.com:80` and the SSL is issued by Sectigo, and the certificate is also available at the path `/etc/docker/certs.d/reg.xxxx.com:80/ca.crt`, the pipeline still fails with:

> Error response from daemon: Get "https://reg.xxxx.com:80/v2/":
> x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

The yaml code for this stage is:

```
pack: 
  image: docker:latest
  stage: pack
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/reg.xxxx.com:80
    - cp $CERT /etc/docker/certs.d/reg.xxxx.com:80/ca.crt
    - cat /etc/docker/certs.d/reg.booqall.com:80/ca.crt
    - docker build -t xxxx/$NAME:latest build/$NAME/dist/.
    - docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASS reg.xxxx.com:80
    - docker push xxxx/$NAME:latest
    - docker push xxxx/$NAME:$CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

How can I resolve this issue? Why is an SSL that is issued by Sectigo is considered unknown authority!!??

Comment: Did you try `--insecure-registry`? It is more like a workaround than a fix.

Comment: @Martin: No, can you please provide more information on this?

Comment: As of Docker 1.3.1, you can do `--insecure-registry dev.registry.com:5000`
 you can replace `5000` with whichever port your registry is listening on.

Comment: @Martin I use `Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701` and `docker login --insecure-registry reg.xxxx.com:80` shows `unknown flag: --insecure-registry`

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: @Martin: It's the Gitlab's CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: @Martin: Outside of it, I don't have any problem

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think the daemon (the dind service) needs the cert, not necessarily the client. Normally you would configure the carts as mounted volumes in the runner configuration (Which will apply to service and job containers)

Comment: @sytech: Would you please provide more information on how I can do this?

Comment: There has been a known issue with `docker:dind` service in Gitlab CI/CD. Sometimes putting variables explicitly to turn off Docker TLS on `variables:` section in `.gitlab-ci.yml` file fixes it. 

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1842#note_536590726

You can see this link and try `DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2`, `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""` in `variables` globally and see if it works.

Another link: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1350#note_205218868